# CMake Xcode generator creates a project that cannot build

Tags: xcode, cmake, generator

I have a C++ project that uses the CMake build system. I use a MacBook Pro for development, so when I use the terminal everything works like a charm, and I can build my project.

However, today I found out that I could use Xcode after creating the respective project using the CMake generator:

```
$> cmake -G Xcode .
```

It works the project and it looks fine, except for the fact that I can't build anything. It doesn't recognize symbols included from included files. Why is this? It seems as if the CMake environmental variables are not passed to Xcode.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the specific error you're seeing? Is it "can't find include file xyz.h" or something else in the Xcode build output?

Comment: The CMake Xcode generator works just fine on CMake itself, as can be seen by the nightly dashboard results for CMake (seen at http://www.cdash.org/CDash/index.php?project=CMake ). Have you tried an "out-of-source" build? What environment variables are you referring to? What is the specific error that you see? Can we see your source code?

Answer (score 5):

Omit the dot (.) in your command invocation, leaving just `cmake -G Xcode`. When I first started using CMake, I also was generating Xcode projects that would not build. I was using CMake's interactive wizard UI, which led to a world of hurt. As often happens, using the simplest command is often the way to go. Once I stopped using the wizard and just using the defaults, I got an Xcode project that builds reliably.

Comment: I don't understand why, but this worked like a charm.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: By the way, I found that CMake also doesn't like when you try to make the project in a directory that has a / character in the name and complains that it can't build it.  Use simplified names instead for your working directories with only alphanumeric characters