# CMake for an Xcode target vs. a normal target

Tags: xcode, c++11, cmake

I have this simple C++11 code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    A(A& a) {}
    A(int x) {this->x = x;}
    int get() {return x;}
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<A>> v;
    auto a = new A(10);
    unique_ptr<A> pa(a);
    v.push_back(move(pa)); // move(pa);

    auto a2 = new A(20);
    unique_ptr<A> pb(a2);
    v.push_back(move(pb)); // move(pa);

    for (auto& i: v)
    {
        cout << i->get();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build this code with a CMake setup on Xcode and clang++.

This is the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( testit )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")

set(testit
    testit.cpp
    )

add_executable(gv ${testit})
```

### clang++ build.

1. `mkdir build` and `cd build`
2. `export CC=/usr/bin/clang`
3. `export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++`
4. `cmake ..`
5. `make`

I could get the binary that works fine.

#### Xcode 4.5 target

1. Same step 1-3
2. `cmake .. -G Xcode`
3. `xcodebuild`

Compilation works fine, but I got an error in the build with `Undefined symbol` error.
I setup C++11 with this command in CMake `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")`.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > > >::__push_back_slow_path<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > >(std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >&&) in testit.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in testit.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in testit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What might be wrong?

#### ADDED

From this link, it seems that the target setup is wrong with the xbuildcode from CMake:
http://www.executionunit.com/blog/2012/10/27/xcode-std-link-errors/

#### ADDED

I could fix this issue, but I had to use the same directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` file is located.

[image]

When I execute `CMake .. -G XCode` I got another error.

```
=== BUILD AGGREGATE TARGET ZERO_CHECK OF PROJECT XcodeTest WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Debug) ===
Check dependencies

PhaseScriptExecution "CMake Rules" build/XcodeTest.build/Debug/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-BED7FB205C634C34A1ACD293.sh
    cd /Users/smcho/Desktop/cmake
    /bin/sh -c /Users/smcho/Desktop/cmake/build/XcodeTest.build/Debug/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-BED7FB205C634C34A1ACD293.sh
echo ""

make -f /Users/smcho/Desktop/cmake/build/CMakeScripts/ReRunCMake.make
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/Users/smcho/Desktop/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake', needed by `CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache'.  Stop.
make: *** [/Users/smcho/Desktop/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/ZERO_CHECK] Error 2
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution "CMake Rules" build/XcodeTest.build/Debug/ZERO_CHECK.build/Script-BED7FB205C634C34A1ACD293.sh
```

Comment: Did you also try passing `-stdlib=libc++` to the linker?  `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")`

Comment: @Fraser: Thanks, it works with your hint.

Comment: The `www.executionunit.com` link is broken (*"Not Found. The requested item could not be located."*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two issues.

### Linker option

As Fraser pointed out, the issue was from setup in the linker.

```
...    
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
...
```

### Add_subdirectory

I'm not sure why is this for, but I needed to use `add_subdirectory(src)` in the main CMakeLists.txt file, and make another CMakeLists.txt file in that `src` directory in order to run CMake in the build directory. Without it, I had to run CMake in the same directory where the CMakeLists.txt file is located. See Stack Overflow question *[CMake Xcode generator creates a project that cannot build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961123/cmake-xcode-generator-creates-a-project-that-cannot-build)*

This is the CMakeLists.txt in the `src` directory:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
file ( GLOB SRCS *.cpp )
add_executable( program ${SRCS})
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt in the main directory:

```
project( XcodeTest )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")

add_subdirectory(src)
```

I got the hint from this YouTube video: *[CMake XCode Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uEXVOzd364)*

[image]